# viewDidLoad called before applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, uitableview, appdelegate

I have a problem that I'm not able to solve by myself. I have to download data from my Web server before the user can see the View(`UITableViewController`), so at the time that the `UITableView` should be visible, it should have the content to show. The problem is, I start downloading the data in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, I have `NSLogs` in `viewDidLoad` and in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, the funny thing is that the `NSLogs` of the `viewDidLoad` are called before the `NSLogs` of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` (those `NSLogs` are wrote just after all the data is downloaded).

Once i finish downloading the data, i have an `NSMutableArray` that i pass from the `AppDelegate` to the `TableViewController`, but the `tableViewController` appears totally empty because the `ViewDidLoad` is called before all the data has been downloaded.

Then I have 1 question: Where i should download all the data before the `TableView` is loaded?

**Solution that I´ve been thinking about:** I thought about creating another `ViewController`(It would be the main View) with an `UIImageView` that have the image " Loading... ": There I download all the data that I need and I store all the Data to an `NSMutableArray`. After the data is downloaded, I call the `UITableViewController` and i pass the `NSMutableArray` to the `UITableViewController`. I am sure this solution will work, but it has to be an easier way to solve this.

Comment: Did you try using breakpoints to see whether viewDidLoad acutally getting called before applicationDidFinishLaunching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution would be create a delegate method that tells your ViewController when the download finished. And on the implementation of the method, you call [yourTableView reloadData].

On the class you will download data (on YourDownloadClass.h):

```
@protocol WebServiceConsumerDelegate 

//@required
-(void) requestDidFinishSuccessfully:(NSArray*) resultArray;

@end

@interface YourDownloadClass : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <WebServiceConsumerDelegate> delegate;
```

And on YourDownloadClass.h just after you download data:

```
[self.delegate requestDidFinishSuccessfully:resultArray];
```

Now, go to your TableViewClass.h

```
#import "YourDownloadClass.h"

@interface TableViewClass : UITableViewController <WebServiceConsumerDelegate>
```

Finally, on TableViewClass.m:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 YourDownloadClass* delegateClass = [YourDownloadClass alloc] init];

 // Or if you are downloading on AppDelegate:
 AppDelegate* delegateClass = [UIapplication sharedApplication];

 delegateClass.delegate = self;

}
```

Finally, implement the method:

```
-(void)requestDidFinishSuccessfully:(NSArray*) resultArray{

   //Get the objects of resultArray to use on your table view

   [yourTableView reloadData];

}
```

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: How i can create that method?